# Google Geocoding Api "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I am using the Google geo-coding API with its API Key; I am using code as below:

```
string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + area + "," + City + "&Key=ABZIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

After handling some requests I am getting the status code "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT";
does any one have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Either you are sending too many requests or you are sending the requests too fast: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usage_exceed

Comment: how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Make a pause after each x requests. (Don't know what an appropriate value for x would be).

Comment: I'm only dealing with a very small data set. How can I set a pause after each 5 requests? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard version is limited to 2 500 daily requests and 10 requests per second:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

You should throttle requests to stay within allowed per second limit. If you need more than 2 500 daily requests you can enable Billing and get 100 000 daily requests.